# Get connected serial Modem logs from putty

Tags: logging, terminal, command, putty, modem

We have connected a USR US Robotics V92 5637 modem to our windows system and using putty as a terminal to send commands to the modem. However some commands like flash `ATDTn!n` are returning `ERROR` as response but we wanted to know the stack trace or the full reason why modem has returned the error ? 
How can we get the full trace of the modem error log from command fired over serial connection from putty ?

Comment: putty will only log the characters that are sent to it - not the modem state...

Comment: @ThomasDickey Thanks for your suggestion but can any tool or other application help us in achieving this ?